# Is there a way to set different default browser for different URLs in win 10

Tags: browser, default-settings

I would like to know if different URLs can be opened on different default browsers.
Ex: https://abcd/xyz, https://abcd/qwert should all be opened in IE and the rest of the URLs in chrome

Comment: You could add shortcuts for those URLs to open with a specific browser.

Comment: thanks, am looking for something which can open different URLs like something in an email/IM or while accessing a URL from a website

Answer (score 4):

1. Write a Powershell or batch script that takes the URL as a parameter, examines it, and launches the appropriate browser to open it.
2. Register your script as the default protocol handler for http, https, ftp, etc.

Comment: No one should be up-voting an "answer" that doesn't answer the question. In the absolute very least a reference to a working example should be provided.